# Adding bulk Msol Users to Msol Group

Tags: shell, powershell, automation, office365, exchange-server

I am trying to add a bulk of users from a CSV file to a MsolGroup via PowerShell. I have only the username of the users. (User.name)
This is what I tried:

**1. Read the CSV file with the userName and get the Msol user object from it:**

```
$group | % {Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.name}
```

**2. Add these ObjectID's to the requested MsolGroup:**

```
$group | % {Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.name} | % {Add-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId 86bbcf6b-feb6-4fe3-a9db-eb1e0b81ed55 -GroupMemberObjectId $_.objectid
```

This is the Error I get:

> Add-MsolGroupMember : You cannot update mail-enabled groups using this
>   cmdlet. Use Exchange Online to perform this operation.

Is there a better way to do it? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the error message, `this cmdlet will only work against "regular" security groups`. For mail-enabled security groups, use the Exchange remote PowerShell and `Add-DistributionGroupMember`

Refer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/add-distributiongroupmember?view=exchange-ps)

Answer (score 0):

We could use

$group | % {Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $*.name} | % {Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "86bbcf6b-feb6-4fe3-a9db-eb1e0b81ed55" -Member $*.objectid